# How to read files from directory in python

Tags: python, csv, subprocess, readfile

My code looks like this

```
from subprocess import check_output  
print(check_output(["ls", "../input"]).decode("utf8"))
```

Can anyone pls explain me this above code
and how to get the train.CSV file from this directory??

Comment: Have you considered `os.listdir('../input')`?

Answer (score 1):

`print(check_output(["ls", "../input"]).decode("utf8"))`

This command prints the output of `ls ../input` as is. It will list the files one per row.

You need to save this output instead of printing it and then checks if the file exists

```
>>> a = check_output(["ls", "."]).decode("utf8")
>>> 'train.CSV' in a
True
```

This will validate the file exists in the directory.

To read it, you should use csv reader something like

```
with open('../input/train.CSV', 'rb') as csvfile:
    your code here
```